# navbar header didn't move leftside

Tags: css, html, layout, grid

[image]

can you help me. my header navbar didn't move to leftside. i want my header to be in corner. it did not change when i used css code. and  even the text color. i use font-color and color but did'nt event change. what the problem of my code?

also the header navbar it's not responsive.  did'nt working

```css
.head2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: black;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding-left: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav .navbar-nav li a {
  color: white;
}

.color-me {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header head2 col-sm-2 ">
      <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">androbo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Did you add bootstrap to the project?

Comment: yes sir. i already put bootstrap

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, add this to your CSS

```
.container-fluid {   padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default you parent element `.container-fluid` has a padding left and right set of 15px... You need to remove that padding in your `.container-fluid`, I would recommend you to create a CSS rule like below and apply it to any element you need/want to to remove the padding:

```
.no-padding {
  padding: 0 !important;
 }
```

```css
.head2{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-left:-10px;
  }

.navbar{
background-color:black;
}
.navbar-brand {
padding-left:70px;
 text-align: center;}

.nav .navbar-nav li a{
color:white;
}
.color-me{
   color:white; 
 }
 .no-padding {
  padding: 0 !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                  <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
                    <div class="navbar-header head2 col-xs-3 " >
                        <a class="navbar-brand "  href="#">androbo</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with Bootstrap framework.
kindly see to this:[Bootsrtap navbar](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/).This will solve your problem.